# Синтаксис интерполяции переменных в PHP

Tags: php

Как правильно вставить `$_SESSION['id']` в запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phonebook_data WHERE id = '$_SESSION['id']' ");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phonebook_data WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']);
```

Но не забывайте фильтровать id хотя бы так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phonebook_data WHERE id = ".intval($_SESSION['id']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам сказал, но это уже действительно перебор, вам дорога [сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php),
учите строки. Запрос тут не причём

Comment: @Gedweb: скорее, [сюда](http://bobby-tables.com/). То, что хочет ТС? подвержено [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).